# Add Dynamic Key Value pair to PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell

i have a script which emits comma separated values for a particular variable and its always dynamic, how can i separate them into multiple key value pairs, i tried the below but the output array gives only values[0] and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H9k4.png)

```
$tagsd = @()

foreach ($a in $vms)

{

$tags = (($a.ExtensionData.GetResourceProperties()).property | ?{$_.name -eq 'summary|tag'}).value.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').split(",").trim()
#<vSphere Tag-Production>, <Cost Center-90210>


$Object = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
        VmName = $a.name
}




0..$tags.count | % {


Add-Member -InputObject $Object -NotePropertyName "VMtag$_" -NotePropertyValue $tags[$_]


}

$tagsd += $Object

}
```

But the output comes as below, even export csv gives me the same

[image]

But the array consists of all the values as seen below, some VM's have Tag1 to Tag 5 but i get only VMtag[0] and VMtag[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H9k4.png), can some one helpw?, i wanted all the tag values to be part of export csv.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the table is created according to the first object. If you want to display all the columns:

```
$propNames = $tagsd | foreach { $_.psobject.Properties.Name } | select -Unique
$tagsd | select $propNames
```

Also, it looks like there are other problems with your code.

If `$tags` has only one value (eg `$tags = "none"`), `$tags[0]` will return the first character "n" rather than the string "none". so you can work around this by either `[array]$tags = ...` or `$tags = @(...)`.

In addition, the range should be `0..($tags.Count -1)` instead of `0..$tags.Count`.

```
$tagsd = @()

foreach ($a in $vms) {

    [array]$tags = (($a.ExtensionData.GetResourceProperties()).Property | where { $_.Name -eq 'summary|tag' }).Value.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Split(",").Trim()

    $object = [pscustomobject]@{ VmName = $a.Name }
    if($tags.Count) {
        0..($tags.Count - 1) | foreach {
            $object | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "VMtag$_" -NotePropertyValue $tags[$_]
        }
    }

    $tagsd += $object
}
```

If possible, it is better to avoid index access to array.

```
$tagsd = foreach ($a in $vms) {
    $tags = (($a.ExtensionData.GetResourceProperties()).Property | where { $_.Name -eq 'summary|tag' }).Value.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Split(",").Trim()

    $h = [ordered]@{ VmName = $a.Name }
    $tags | foreach { $i = 0 } { $h.Add("VMtag${i}", $_); $i++ }
    [pscustomobject]$h
}
$propNames = $tagsd | foreach { $_.psobject.Properties.Name } | select -Unique
$tagsd | select $propNames
```